# [Solved]failed catkin_make on rosjava

Tags: raspberrypi, ros-kinetic, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava/Tutorials/kinetic/Source%20Installation

I tried [3.1 Core Sources].

Errors on catkin_make.

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/9f6db8f28312a0d738a401278cab01db

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277386/%5Bsolved%5Dfailed-catkin_make-on-rosjava/) by [ramekabi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32877/ramekabi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@ramekabi this is a known issue with JDK7; it fails downloading the Gradle distribution. You can take a look here: https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core/issues/252; you should find some workarounds there.

The easiest one is using JDK 8 (from OpenJDK or from Oracle, it shouldn't make a difference). Don't forget to set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable properly. That should solve your problem.

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2017-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ramekabi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32877/ramekabi/) on 2017-12-06**:
Thank you.

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2017-12-06**:
Did that work for you? If so, please mark the answer as accepted so as others can use it.